# Cloud Run deployed REST API failing on only specific endpoints

Tags: node.js, docker, google-cloud-run, objection.js

So I'm trying to deploy my NodeJS rest API on Cloud Run and for the most part it deploys successfully except a couple endpoints seem to be failing with either a 404 or 500 error. However when I run the container locally using `docker run -p 8080:8080 <image>` all the endpoints work. The common thing between all the failing endpoints seem to be that they are accessing the remote database using the credentials stored in the `.env` file.

EDIT: I think it is because the database is on a private internal ip so I'm trying to figure out what I would need to do for that

Comment: where is your database hosted? Were you trying to connect to Cloud SQL? If yes, which database engine are you using?

Comment: What are the characteristics of your endpoint to make them not working?

Comment: @MabelA. I think it is because my database is on a private internal network so I looked into serverless VPC Access but it costs $12-$60/month with no free tier. Is there a free workaround or a something that has a free tier just to test if this is even the issue?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere The common thing between all the failing endpoints seem to be that they are accessing the remote database using the credentials stored in the .env file. So,  I think it is because my database is on a private internal network

Comment: If your database have only private IP, indeed you need a serverless VPC connector to reach it. But you can also make it public, with no authorized network. It's like a public IP with a deny all firewall rule. But you will be able to reach it with the Cloud SQL connector on Cloud Run and therefore solve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @guillaume, if your database is on a private internal network then VPC connector is necessary. You can use the [Connecting from Cloud Run to Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run) documentation as guide whether you stick to the private IP only or decided to use a public IP which will not require a VPC connector.